# PHP fetch comments from MySQL and edit/enable/disable to show on comments page

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I have a comments/testimonials form which saves data into MySQL database testimonials. Now through admin page I want to edit and enable or disable the comments which should show on my comments page. I don't know how to do this.

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonials` ORDER BY 

`t_id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());

if(!$query) {echo "Error!";} else { echo "Testimonials";}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name,City</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Comment</th>
<th>Enable</th>
<th>Edit</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['t_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['t_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['t_email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['t_message'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['enable'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['edit'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Now I want a checkbox to show where $row['enable'] is and an Edit & Save/Update button where $row['edit'] is. When I click 'edit' button I can edit the fields and save them to Database. When I check the checkbox the value in 'enable' field pertaining to those particular comments in database is updated to 'True' so that those can display on the Testimonials page.

Comment: so.. What have you tried & where do you get stuck?

Comment: i dont know where to start. i mean do i enter a text box on other fields and a form submit where $row['edit'] is. will that work? if so then how do i do it

Comment: You need to look up basic mysql and php web development tutorials. You should not be using [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/mysql_query) as it's deprecated. [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) replace it.

Comment: ok thanks i'll do that

Comment: This question can be closed as Needs Focus.